# Finding stationary points of a function.

Tags: multivariable-calculus

I need to find stationary points for a function $z(x,y) = e^{-x^2-y^2}$ under a condition: $x^2 - y^2 = 1$.

My attempt:

I take partial derivatives of a function: $e^{-x^2-y^2} + \lambda(x^2 - y^2 -1)$

Partial derivative with respect to $x$: $e^{-x^2-y^2}  (-2x) + 2\lambda x$

Partial derivative with respect to $y$: $e^{-x^2-y^2}(-2y) - 2\lambda y$

When I set partial derivative with respect to $x$ to be equal $0$, I get $x = 0$, or $e^{-x^2-y^2} = \lambda$

Same thing with the other partial derivative. I get $y = 0$ or $e^{-x^2-y^2} = -\lambda$

I don't know how to continue from this point on. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Now you have four possible cases (but not all of them give valid solutions).

Comment: A) At stationary points both derivatives must be 0, and B) use the condition $x^2-y^2=1$. There are now 3 equations with 3 variables.

Comment: Just to note, because $f(u) = e^{-u}$ has no critical points it's equivalent to find  stationary points of $g(x, y) = x^2+y^2$ under the same constraint.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The solution $x=0$ is not compatible with the condition $x^2-y^2=1$, so it must be discarded. Therefore, the alternative $e^{-x^2-y^2}=\lambda$ must be true. Let's now consider the other two possibilities:

1. $y=0$: in this case, the condition $x^2-y^2=1$ implies $x=\pm 1$. This gives us two solutions: $(x,y)=(-1,0)$ or $(x,y)=(1,0)$.
2. $e^{-x^2-y^2}=-\lambda$: combined with $e^{-x^2-y^2}=\lambda$, they imply $\lambda=0$, but that's not possible, for $e^{-x^2-y^2}\neq 0$.

Comment: Got it.If I wanted to find extreme values of a function, should I then plug the values of $x$ and $y$ to get value of $\lambda$ ?

Answer (score 1):

Hints: $\lambda$ cannot be $0$. If it is positive then $e^{-x^2-y^2} = -\lambda$ is truled out, so you get $y=0$. Either $x=0$ or $-x^{2}-y^{2}=\ln \lambda$. So $x=0$ or $x=\sqrt {-\ln \lambda}$. You need $\ln \lambda \leq 0$ or $\lambda \leq 1$ for this. Can you proceed from here?

Similar arguments can be used when $\lambda <0$.